# Creating Country > State > City lists in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been tasked with creating a dynamic list of sorts for a WordPress page.  I'll have a list of countries, and then when a country is picked, the next list is populated with states in that country, and then the next menu, with cities in that state.

I've been unable to find a definitive solution on this, have searched far and wide.

Does anyone have any idea how to implement this, or where I could find it in a plugin perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Too much trouble....
here...

```
function datak()
{
  $url = 'http://api.sba.gov/geodata/city_links_for_state_of/tx.json';
  $crl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $rtn = curl_exec($crl);
  $srn = json_decode($rtn);
  $nmb=0;
  echo "<select name='state' id='state'><option value='-1'>Choose a state</option>";
  while( $nmb < count($srn) ) {   
    echo '<option value="' . $srn[$nmb]->name . '">' . $srn[$nmb]->name . ' - ' . $srn[$nmb]->primary_longitude . ' - ' . $srn[$nmb]->primary_latitude . "</option>" ; 
    $nmb++;
  }
  echo "</select>";
  curl_close($crl);
      }
```

It needs some cleanup and ordering-there are dup entries. Change the state prefix in the url and if you want you can set the file-type to xml but you will have to re-code the procedure.

Let someone else do the datakeeping.
 Just give users the content.

Got it [here](http://www.sba.gov/about-sba-services/7617/).

Hope this helps.
isme

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugins that have exactly what you need, but if I were to personally build it from scratch, I would first look over [This Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463004/free-sql-script-to-get-a-list-of-countries-provinces-states-and-their-cities) on populating a database with all of the information for each city.

Information would be organized like so:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Country   |   State   |   Province   |   City   |  Latitude  |  Longitude   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

with each city being its own row in the database. Latitude and Longitude would be optional, but recommended.

After that, it would be a matter of using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to populate your dropdowns on the fly. Basically, you can use jQuery (recommended for this task, since we don't want to reinvent the wheel) to pass a GET or POST request to a separate PHP script. This file will run an SQL Query (be sure to avoid the mysql_* functions, as they're being deprecated. Look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for a better alternative) and check the values that are passed into it against the database.

I would recommend populating your database with some basic information. Perhaps set it up with a few States and Cities, and then look into the resources I've given you to get a working proof of concept going.

If you run into any stumbling blocks, feel free to open up another question so we can help you out.

Good luck.

Comment: The "This information" link is not working anymore!

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to display the list of country-state-cities for the world. Just add the following HTML and javascript to your template

```
<select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
<select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
<select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://lab.iamrohit.in/js/location.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/hiiamrohit/Countries-States-Cities-database